# Infinite Ajax Scroll Reset PageNum

Tags: jquery, ajax, scroll, reset, infinite

I use this jQuery plugin:
https://github.com/webcreate/infinite-ajax-scroll

I want to reset Numpage (or some like that) on filtering (my code):

```
        $(document).on("change", "#typefilter, #loginfilter", function(){
            var typefilter = $("#typefilter").find('option:checked').val() || '';
            var loginfilter = $("#loginfilter").find('option:checked').val() || '';
            var datestart = $('input[name=datefrom]').val() || '';
            var dateend = $('input[name=dateto]').val() || '';

            toload(loginfilter, typefilter, datestart, dateend);

/* want to call reset here */
       });
```

Because last page saved to history and when I do filter, scrolling starts from last saved page... I need to starts from begin.

Answer (score 0):

Theres already a `forceScrollTop` function defined to do the same thing have you checked it out?

Comment: Never might I use other script.